# How can I enable the ld.so Secure Execution mode?

Tags: linux

As per the ld.so man page the secure execution mode can be enabled if the AT_SECURE entry in the auxiliary vector has a non-zero value.
But How to set this AT_SECURE entry to a non-zero value?

At the man page the possible reasons are mentioned for which the AT_SECURE entry may have the non-zero value. But I want to set the secure execution mode permanently. Is it Possible to do?

Comment: `How to set` My man pages says:`This entry may have a nonzero value for various reasons, including:` and then follows with methods to set it.

Comment: Those reasons on the man page seems to me like if any of those situations happen it will set the secure execution mode. But here purposely I want to set it to secure execution mode permanently.

Comment: `But here purposely` Then you have to modify kernel to set that information. Or "purposely" make one of the mentioned cases. Did you see `man getauxval(3)`? `mechanism that the ****kernel's**** ELF binary loader uses to
       pass certain information` - if you want to do that purposefully, you have to modify the kernel and allow somehow to notify kernel that you want it.

Comment: Actually I was thinking not to modify kernel and thought if I could find any other better and easier way to do it. If any?